# how to update page source

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a simple test file for adding custom list items with hrefs to a list, it works but when I refresh the page the list items are gone because the actual page source isn't updated. How do update the page source and keep the list items?

I don't think you'll need to see the js to answer but here it is anyway.

```
  var list = document.getElementById('list');
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  var button = document.getElementById('button');

  function addListItem(){
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var linkValue = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    var listText = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    var link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = linkValue
    link.appendChild(listText)
    listItem.appendChild(link);
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(listItem);
```

Comment: `How do update the page source` you update it on the server

Comment: Updating the source would mean to rewrite the file on the server. There is no standard way to do so. The webserver would have to provide such an endpoint and make sure that only authorized users can rewrite the source. But maybe what you actually need is a database to store user submitted data and generate the HTML dynamically from that data. Impossible to say with so little information.

Comment: you could save the values in a cookie

Comment: I dont think u can update the page source dynamically. You can use session variables or u save it into a database. Or you can use ajax to update part of your page while adding list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't! The page source is something that you have directly written in your html file or generated on the server side. When it comes to DOM manipulation, what happens in the client side, stays in the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I have used LocalStorage when I want to save data to my computer.

If I did:

```
LocalStorage.setItem("Name","Jhon"); // Store data "Jhon" to storage "Name"
LocalStorage.getItem("Name"); // Returns "Jhon"
```

It will remember what "Name" is even if you reload the page.
However it will always return it as a string.  So you would need to un-string it.

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: `LocalStorage` is executed using JavaScript, so it still happens in the client side.